Calculation time too long for FoxH
Clear["Global`*"];
FoxH[{{}, {}}, {{{0, 0.5}, {-3, 1}}, {}}, 0.2]

Related:

No result from FoxH


$Version
(*"13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"*)

FoxH[{{}, {}}, {{{0, 1/2}, {-3, 1}}, {}}, 2/10] // FunctionExpand
(*MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{-(3/2), -1, 0}, {}}, 1/10, 1/2]/(8 Sqrt[\[Pi]])*)
% // N
(*89.3234*)

FoxH[{{}, {}}, {{{0, 1/2}, {-3, 1}}, {}}, 2/10] // N
(*To long time to compute ! Weakness*)

$Version
(*"14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"*) 

FoxH[{{}, {}}, {{{0, 1/2}, {-3, 1}}, {}}, 2/10] // FunctionExpand
(*Gives Input.Probably a bug in FunctionExpand*)
% // N
(*To long time to compute ! Weakness*)

Using answers from here we have:
FoxHToMeijerG[FoxH[{{}, {}}, {{{0, 1/2}, {-3, 1}}, {}}, x]] /. x -> 0.2
(*89.3234*)

By user's @MichaelE2 advice, can also be used:
Table[FoxH[{{}, {}}, {{{10^-x, 0.5}, {-3, 1}}, {}}, 0.2], {x, 1, 8}] // TableForm

(*{
{91.0126},
{89.4603},
{89.3367},
{89.3247},
{89.3235},
{89.3234},
{89.3234},
{89.3234}}*)


The zero seems to be part of the problem. Does this result seem right?: N[FoxH[{{}, {}}, {{{10^-500, 1/2}, {-3, 1}}, {}}, 2/10], 10]. It suggests that H is approaching $\pm\infty$ as the parameter approaches $0$ and that the  desired value is undefined. I don't know Fox H tho'....

@MichaelE2 .Yes you are right. Asymptotic[FoxH[{{}, {}}, {{{0, 1/2}, {-3, 1}}, {}}, x], x -> 0] gives: ComplexInfinity.Or: N[Table[MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{-(3/2), -1, 0}, {}}, x/2, 1/2]/(    8 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) /. x -> 10^-k, {k, 0, 5}]].

I think my result in the first comment is marred by internal numerical catastrophes. This gives a value more in line with the other values: Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100},  N[FoxH[{{}, {}}, {{{10^-100, 1/2}, {-3, 1}}, {}}, 2/10], 201]  ] (~4 sec.) yields 89.32.... For very small parameters like 10^-100, extra precision is needed internally of about the same magnitude (+200 for 10^-200 for instance, ~34 sec.). I didn't want to wait for 10^-500. However the result for 10^-200 differed from 10^-100 by about 10^-8. If both were accurate, then it's not yet close to machine prec.

@MichaelE2 OP didn't ask for the  precise numeric result.

I just meant that my first thought, that the value should be infinity, is probably wrong, and the high precision (HP) calculation supports the MeijerG value. I would also conjecture that this behavior is connected to the machine precision (MP) N[FoxH[...]] taking so long, but I don't have an idea exactly how it is connected. (I included some HP details simply because I had observed them and decided to share them with whomever might read comments. Also HP seems the fast way to get any sort of MP result from FoxH. I guess MeijerG is better in the end, though)
